# Best way to live in USA as a EU citizen?

Tags: usa, esta

I'm a EU citizen and want to live in USA for a few years.

ESTA is only for 3 months however and I'm guessing I can't just hop out of the country for a week and then return indefinitely.

I have enough savings to live comfortably in NYC/LA but don't have like $500k+ to drop on an investor visa like it's nothing. I do run a few online businesses though so maybe I can open up LLCs in USA and get a business visa of some sort?

What do you recommend or who do you recommend contacting for such problems?

Thanks! :)

Comment: The ESTA is definitely _not_ the way to go. For all other questions regarding long-term immigration please ask on [expatriates.se]

Comment: But note that any question along the lines of "What is the best way to do X?" is likely to be closed as being opinion-based, and "How do I go about living in the USA for a few years?" is far too broad to be reasonably answered.

Comment: Hi new user.  This question should be asked on Expatriates.   It used to be the standard thing that you'd just open a company in the US, and then sponsor yourself to live there.  That *can* still be done to some extent but it's just a bit harder.  in short it is very, very easy to find a good immigration attorney in the US.  It will cost you about $3000 for the attorney fee and about $3000 in other fees to pull this off.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome guys (and gals?), thanks for the tip! Heading over to there!